# Restore data from a Json file using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm having a hard time trying to read in a Json file. My restoreObjects ArrayList is always null. Also, I'm not even sure if I should be parsing the file path like that, But I can't seem to understand how I'm supposed to use ContentResolver. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
public void restoreObjects(Uri backupJsonFile) {

    File backupFilePath = new File(backupJsonFile.getPath());
    String sFile = backupFilePath.toString();
    String split[] = sFile.split(":");
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

    //Get all the current "Objects" that are saved.
    ArrayList<Object> currentObjects = getAllObjects();
    int newid = getNewObjectId();

    try {
        //get contents of Json file 
        JsonReader backupData = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        //This is were the array should be populated, but is left null
        ArrayList<Object> restoreObjects = gsonBuilder.fromJson(backupData, type);

        for (Object rObject : restoreObjects) {
            if (currentObject.contains(rObject.getId())) {
                    //Do work here
            }
        }
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException | NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Threw in this line of code: 
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
Ran a debugger and it was showing an empty string ("")
Is there a permission I'm missing?
My manifest has both read and write permissions.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was combination of not capturing the InputStream and not using getContentResolver to locate the file.

```
public void restoreObjects(Uri backupFile) {
    ArrayList<Object> currentObjects = getAllObjects();
    
    try {
        InputStream is = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(backupFile);

        String jsonString;

        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        
        ArrayList<Object> restoreObjects = gsonBuilder.fromJson(jsonString, type);

        for (Objects rObject : restoreObjects) {
            if (currentObjects.contains(rObject.getId())) {
               //do work
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException | NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "R.string.success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```